# Python 3.x - Sorting 2 or more lists according to the value of 1 of them

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I'm new to Python and I'm working with Python 3.4, but I would like to have an answer that could be work generally on Python 3.x.

I had 3 lists *A*, *B* and *C*.
The first list is a data structure, the second and the third lists are integer values (but if we want to develop a more generic solution they could be of any types).
The values contained in the same position of the 3 lists are related.

I want to sort all the 3 lists according to the values contained in B or in C.
There is an easy way to do that?

Example:

> A = ['orange', 'apple', 'pear', 'kiwi', 'banana'] 
>   B = [415, 450, 420, 480, 400] 
>   C = [3, 2, 1, 5, 3]

Sort according to B:

> A = ['banana', 'orange', 'pear', 'apple', 'kiwi'] 
>   B = [400, 415, 420, 450, 480] 
>   C = [3, 3, 1, 2, 5]

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: show us a sample of the lists and what you've tried so far.

Comment: So you want the exact sorting operations performed on lists B&C on A as well? If yes, I don't think B&C will have similar sorting procedures until they are equal!

Comment: Ubdsus Samad, I want to sort all the lists according to one of them, for example I want to sort B, and I want that A and C will be sorted according to how B was sorted.

Comment: There is an easy way to do that? answer is yes

Comment: Edit your first post, show us a verifiable example along with the code you've tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combine lists, sort by desired index in the complex list and unpack

```
a,b,c = zip(*sorted(zip(a,b,c), key = lambda x: x[0]))
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/937701)

Comment: Can you please explain it in parts (if you have time)?

Comment: I added prints after each step, look there - https://eval.in/937707 . If questions stil will be, write here

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
def sort_by_key(key, **kwargs):
  return {a:list(map(lambda c:c[0], sorted(zip(b, range(len(b))), key=lambda x:kwargs[key][x[-1]]))) for a, b in kwargs.items()}

print(sort_by_key('B', A = ['orange', 'apple', 'pear', 'kiwi', 'banana'], B = [415, 450, 420, 480, 400], C = [3, 2, 1, 5, 3]))
```

Output:

```
{'A': ['banana', 'orange', 'pear', 'apple', 'kiwi'], 'C': [3, 3, 1, 2, 5], 'B': [400, 415, 420, 450, 480]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use this function :

```
A = ['orange', 'apple', 'pear', 'kiwi', 'banana']
B = [415, 450, 420, 480, 400]
C = [3, 2, 1, 5, 3]


def sorted_by_list(target_lists,source_list):
    result=[]
    for sub_list in target_lists:


        result.append([i[1] for i in sorted(zip(source_list,sub_list))])
    return result

print(sorted_by_list([A,B,C],B))
```

output:

```
[['banana', 'orange', 'pear', 'apple', 'kiwi'], [400, 415, 420, 450, 480], [3, 3, 1, 2, 5]]
```